# ADC digital data out is decreased by 1

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega, adc

I've been working in an ADC project on ATmega 32
my ADC is 10-bit resolution, Vref = 2.56V (internally
from this information I can conclude that step size =  2.56/1024 = 2.5mV

then, if the input voltage is 2.5 volt, the Digital data output must be 2.5V /2.5mV = 1000 = 0b1111101000

I've made that code and make a simulation in proteus, but when the input voltage was 2.5V, the output was 999 (decimal) =  0b1111100111 instead of 1000 why??!!

Note: the digital data output is right adjusted

that's my code:

## include

```
int main(void)
{
    DDRB = 0xFF;
    DDRD = 0xFF;
    DDRA = 0;
    ADCSRA = 0x87;          //ADC enable, clk/128
    ADMUX = 0xC0;           //Internal vref, single ended ADC0
    while(1){
    ADCSRA |=(1<<ADSC);     //start conversion
    while(ADCSRA & (1<<ADIF) == 0);
    PORTD = ADCL;
    PORTB = ADCH;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the output of the proteus simulation

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your math is a little off. At 0V, the ADC output is 0, hence there are only **1023** steps to reach 2.56V.

2.5V / (2.56V / 1023) = 999.02344

Comment: but I get this math calculations from "AVR microcontroller and embedded systems using assembly and C" and its writer is mazidi,
He said that the step size = (Vref/ 2^n) where n is the resolution of the ADC (not 2^(n-1))

Comment: @ArmiaWagdy: I've never read that work, but that math is incorrect.

Comment: Imagine you have 1 bit ADC, i.e. 0 and 1 values. You have 2 values but only 1 "gap" to divide.